# Unzip a .tar file using Jenkins pipeline and store in a new folder in a workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, tar, jenkins-groovy, workspace

I have a zip file with name ***.tar which was downloaded from artifact and saved in workspace. I used below command to unzip it and store it in a new folder in the workspace. But I didn't get required output. Could you please let me know how can I unzip this .tar file?

```
function Unzip{
 param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)
 [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

Unzip "D:\Jenkins\workspace\PracticeJobs\test_artfact_download\huge\C1-Jupiter-PPAP-ALL-dbg.tar" "D:\Jenkins\workspace\PracticeJobs\test_artfact_download\huge\"
$DirName =  Get-ChildItem "D:\Jenkins\workspace\PracticeJobs\test_artfact_download\huge\C1-Jupiter-PPAP-ALL-dbg"

foreach ( $item in $DirName){
 Unzip "D:\Jenkins\workspace\PracticeJobs\test_artfact_download\huge\C1-Jupiter-PPAP-ALL-dbg\$item" "D:\Jenkins\workspace\PracticeJobs\test_artfact_download\huge\C1-Jupiter-PPAP-ALL-dbg\"
}
```

Comment: Is ${DirName} resolved into only 1 name ("D:\Jenkins\workspace\PracticeJobs\test_artfact_download\huge\C1-Jupiter-PPAP-ALL-dbg"), or to all the names contained by "D:\Jenkins\workspace\PracticeJobs\test_artfact_download\huge\C1-Jupiter-PPAP-ALL-dbg" ?

Comment: Why do you need to specify 2 parameters for Unzip, if the output directory is the same as the content of the original zip file ?  That form is reserved for when the two are different, AFAIK.